Is intuitionistic logic a subsystem of classical logic?
Joan Moschovakis' Intuitionistic Logic claims:

"Although intuitionistic analysis conflicts with classical analysis, intuitionistic Heyting arithmetic is a subsystem of classical Peano arithmetic. It follows that intuitionistic propositional logic is a proper subsystem of classical propositional logic, and pure intuitionistic predicate logic is a proper subsystem of pure classical predicate logic."

What is the meaning of 'pure' in this quote, as well as this answer to a related question? (Another related response but I think it only applies to propositional/predicate logic.) Can we generalize Moschovakis' statement to "intuitionistic logic is a proper subsystem of classical logic"? Or is the jump from first to second-order logic (e.g, characterizing $\mathbb{R}$) where the subsystem relation breaks down? Something related to the 'pure' property?

I would interpret "pure" to mean atomized in this context, so in its simplest form. I don't think the word pure carries any significance here and you can just ignore it in the sentence without any loss.

@CyclotomicField That's not quite true, "pure" has a technical meaning here. It means that we're looking at the "axiom-free" fragment - that is, "pure intuitionistic logic is contained in pure classical logic" is shorthand for "every intuitionistic tautology is a classical tautology."
